Skipping Database Configuration in @SpringBootTest
I'm using @SpringBootTest for integration testing in Spring Boot, and I want to mock database calls without connecting to the real database. However, I want to skip scanning the database configuration file to ensure the tests don't attempt real database connections.  How to achieve this?
I have tried enableautoconfiguration, exclude, testconfiguration but nothing works

Can you provide the test class, and any configuration being used as well as properties file, whichever minimal configuration you are using.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
